# The bulk of assets was /were?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I understand that assets is in plural form but not sure about the following sentences:-

The bulk of its assets were tied in property

or

The bulk of its assets was tie in property.

Comment: See this [note](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/bulk): "The use of a plural noun after bulk, when it has the meaning 'majority', although common, is considered by some to be incorrect and should be avoided. This usage is most commonly encountered, according to the Bank of English, when referring to funds and profits: the bulk of our profits stem from the sale of beer. The synonyms majority and most would work better in this context."

Comment: @DamkerngT. It's again the case of collective nouns. Both singular and plural are possible depending on the perception of the speaker.

Comment: If *was* were correct, it would be "was tied", not "was tie".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are hard and fast rules here.  However, I think most native language speakers would make a distinction based on whether 'bulk' was explicitly referring to a *count* noun or a *mass* noun.

Typical count nouns: dolls, houses, people
Typical mass nouns: butter, information, music

> When I was at the department store I saw dozens of toy cars.  The bulk of them **were** red.
>
> When I was at the festival I heard a lot of music.  The bulk of it **was** awful.

In the first sentence, 'was' is possible, but in my estimate, MUCH less likely, especially in speech:

> When I was at the department store I saw dozens of toy cars.  The bulk of them **was** red.

Compare

> The majority of the population was/were happy.
>
> The majority of the figurines were broken.

Comment: I find the end of your answer confusing. I can compare, but it doesn't help me know which one is better (*if I naturally knew what sounded natural, I wouldn't be asking*). I think I understand what you say, but it really hinges on 2 words in the middle line (**was** is **less** likely). Maybe you can make this easier to understand by marking correct sentences and incorrect sentences ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fit this sentence the way subject-verb agreement is described [here](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/singular-vs-plural/subject-and-verb-agreement-with-collective-nouns/).

> Do you use a singular or plural verb to match a collective noun such as *team or staff*? The answer is, It depends. If these nouns are acting as a unit, use a singular verb.

Also, I could not find collective noun taking *its* or form the like on [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun) and even on the list of collective nouns at several places.

I guess in the case of collective nouns the pronoun *its* shouldn't be there here. Clearly, it's talking about **the bulk** which is [singular](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/bulk_1) and hence would take **was** in my opinion.

Comment: Both was/were are possible, depending on what you said. But still we can use both. It's BrE and AmE difference, I guess.

Comment: @Man_From_India which reference we can have for the term *bulk* as a collective noun? Especially when the pronoun further talks about it?

Comment: *[ The rest of the eggs ] **were** on the table*, versus *[ The rest of the salt ] **was** on the table*.  This is an exception to the normal rules of agreement.  Here, a smaller NP inside the subject NP apparently determines the number the verb agrees with.

Comment: @snailplane in any case, do we use *salt* with *were?* Especially like the example you gave here? Also, where *bulk* is called a collective noun? I'm also interested in that.

Comment: *The salt **was** on the table.*

Comment: @snailplane I asked *salt with were*.